Extract column values using range R
I have two datasets, each has a site column, an x column and a y column. dataset A has an additional column of jph, dataset B has additional columns of xplus1, xminus1, yplus1, yminus 1, and size class. For each site, I want to pull the jph from dataset A when the x and y coordinates are within the range of dataset B's xminus1, xplus1, yplus1, yminus1, and retain the size class and site from dataset B. How can I do this in R with dplyr?
datasetA <- data.frame(
  site = c('Site1', 'Site2', 'Site3'),
  x = c(1, 5, 9),
  y = c(2, 6, 10),
  jph = c(100, 200, 300)
)

datasetB <- data.frame(
  site = c('Site1', 'Site2', 'Site3'),
  xplus1 = c(2, 6, 10),
  xminus1 = c(0, 4, 8),
  yplus1 = c(3, 7, 11),
  yminus1 = c(1, 5, 9),
  fish_length = c(15, 25, 35)
)


Your question is confusing. What range exactly are you checking for? Row wise or column wise?

It's not clear to me when you say "within the range" if the end points are inclusive are not. In this code they are assumed to be inclusive. You can do all this by creating a join specification:
library(dplyr)

inner_join(datasetA, datasetB, 
           by = join_by(site, between(x, xminus1, xplus1), between(y, yminus1, yplus1)))
#    site x  y jph xplus1 xminus1 yplus1 yminus1 fish_length
# 1 Site1 1  2 100      2       0      3       1          15
# 2 Site2 5  6 200      6       4      7       5          25
# 3 Site3 9 10 300     10       8     11       9          35


it is a simple filter
datasetA %>% 
  left_join(datasetB) %>% 
  filter(xminus1<x, x<xplus1,
         yminus1<y, y<yplus1) %>% 
  select(site, fish_length)

